# How can I make window titlebars black like the GNOME Shell top panel?

Tags: gnome, themes, titlebar

I have recently installed GNOME 3.2 and I would like that the title bars on every program had the same color as the black toolbar that GNOME has, because I have the ambiance title bars and I don't like it. I've looked everywhere but I didn't find any way. Does anyone know how to do it?

Thank you

Answer (score 3):

As indicated by Uri, [gnome-tweak-tool](http://apt.ubuntu.com/p/gnome-tweak-tool) [image: Install gnome-tweak-tool] is extremely helpful for themeing gnome. You can adjust several settings including themes and icons.

```
sudo apt-get install gnome-tweak-tool
```

[image: gtt]

Comment: yeah, I have tweak tools, but the thing is that I don't know which theme I should put so that it looks that way

Comment: If you can not find a theme you like, you can also look at gnome look. http://gnome-look.org/